# Can I stop Google+ from asking me to "Find my friends"?

Tags: google-plus

It seems that whenever I visit Google+, I get a big long screen suggesting people to encircle, like this:

[image]

Is there any way to stop it from nagging me about this? Everyone it suggests is either not my friend or not at all active on G+, and it is a pain finding the little "Continue" button at the bottom every time.

Comment: I think it must stop eventually. I don't see that any more.

Comment: +1 - sooo annoying. @AlEverett it seems to happen to me about 8 out of 10 times. It'll seem to stop, then I get it again. Pffft.

Comment: For what it's worth, I get Facebook asking me much more often. Have you actually used the tool to add a few people? Maybe it'll shut up then.

Answer (score 4):

**Adding people to circles**

This happens because Google thinks you don't have enough people in your circles to get the most out of Google+ and is trying to help you connect with your existing network.

Typical for a new Google+ profile.  Add a few more profiles or Pages to your circles and it'll stop showing the large pop-up.

Here is something I wrote about "[Who sees your post on Google+](http://googleplushelper.blogspot.fi/2012/12/who-sees-your-google-post.html)", hope it helps in the sharing of your posts and content.

Going public is good, especially if you wish to "[attract more followers](http://googleplushelper.blogspot.fi/2012/11/how-to-attract-audience-on-google.html)" and thus get more engagement on your posts.

Comment: This happens to me with **OVER** 50 people in my circles, so there must be something else.

Comment: I don't want more! Yuck!!

Comment: I have over 80 people in my circles and I'm part of several communities, and I see this every notification day.

Answer (score -1):

In the Settinge menu find 'Manage Subscriptions'

Uncheck the two options:
Occasional updates about Google+ activity and friend suggestions
Occasional updates from people outside your circles

Comment: That would seem to be about managing the occasional email message that Google+ sends, not the screen in the G+ app itself.